# How to get Index of element if found using Binary Search(Recursively)

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

```js
function getMiddle({right,left}) {
  return Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
}

function RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr, search) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;
  let middle = getMiddle({left,right});
  if (right >= left) {
    if (arr[middle] === search) {
      return middle;
    } else if (arr[middle] < search) {
      return RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr.slice(middle + 1, arr.length), search);
    } else {
      return RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr.slice(0, middle - 1), search)
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

let result = RecursivelyBinarySearch([1,5,7,9,10,20], 20);
console.log(result);
```

`// RecursivelyBinarySearch([1,5,7,9,10,20], 20)`
RecursivelyBinarySearch returns 0, but I want it to be 5,
is it possible to do this without passing the orignal array?

Comment: Yes: `return left + RecursivelyBinarySearch(...)`.

Comment: @Welbog- how does the `+` operator work with an array? The issue the OP faces is that the return is a mutation of the original array that get's smaller and smaller until the only remaining value in the array is the search value. Hence the index of that value will always be zero. Adding zero to an array (the return value) is not the solution.

Comment: The solution is also not to seek out the array index within a binary search as you blow the efficiency of the algorithm. There are other algorithms to accomplish that goal. (like a simple while loop - faster yet, a traditional `for` loop).

Comment: Bottom line is you cannot mutate an array and expect to get the position of the found element in the original _without passing the original array every time_.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Not sure what you're reading, but this returns an int, and adding the lower bound will yield the correct result, as this accounts for the size of the array omitted when looking at half the remaining array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow! It's a strange request to not pass the original array. But I assume you have a good reason for it :)

Regarding your snippet, you have an error in your Binary Search function. For the last else case you need to pass `arr.slice(0, middle)` instead of `middle - 1`.

Now for your original question, we need to pass the first index of array every time, since this information is critical to find the original index (It is lost when you do arr.slice). You can modify your function like below to achieve the desired result.

```
function getMiddle({right,left}) {
  return Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
}

function RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr, search, first_idx) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;
  let middle = getMiddle({left,right});
  if (right >= left) {
    if (arr[middle] === search) {
      return middle + first_idx;
    } else if (arr[middle] < search) {
      return RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr.slice(middle + 1, arr.length), search, middle + first_idx + 1);
    } else {
      return RecursivelyBinarySearch(arr.slice(0, middle), search, first_idx)
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

let result = RecursivelyBinarySearch([1,5,7,9,10,20], 20, 0);
console.log(result);
```